# Copy directory from user ubuntu to root aws server

Tags: server, permissions, aws

I'm very new to this. I'm trying to copy a directory from user ubuntu to root using this command.

```
scp -i mykey.pem ~/var/www/dj root@ip:/var/www
```

and it says

```
Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".
```

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The reply seems to be in plain language. Did you try doing what it said?

Comment: Yes, but it says `scp: /var/www/dj/file: Permission denied` this time.

Comment: Does `/var/www/dj/` exist? In your command above, you have `~/var/www/dj`, which would be `/home/{user}/var/www/dj` ...

Comment: Yes, it does exist. So how can I copy from `~/var/www/dj ` to `/var/www/dj/ ` ? it said Permission denied

Comment: User `ubuntu` probably doesn't have write access to `/var/www` on the server, but probably root login over ssh/scp is disabled (which is a good idea security-wise). Copy the folder temporarily to somewhere in `ubuntu`'s home folder on the server, then ssh into the server (again as ubuntu), and mv the folder with `sudo`.

Comment: Ah ... so you have these files *on the server already*, and you're just trying to move them over? The command you're using is trying to copy from your local computer to remote ...

Answer (score 0):

In the event the files you want to copy are on the server in the `ubuntu` user's home directory, you can copy the files to the intended location by using `sudo` with `cp` (or `mv` if you would like to move them). You will need to first connect to the server via SSH.

1. Connect to the server:

   ```
   ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@ip
   ```
2. Copy the files:

   ```
   sudo cp ~/var/www/dj /var/www
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** If you would like to move the file rather than copy them, replace `cp` with `mv`.</sup>
3. Set the ownership of the files:

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
   ```
4. Set the file permission of the files:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
   ```